# What's the .php file which generates the Custom Background page in the admin panel?

Tags: php, wp-admin

What's the `.php` file which generates the `Appereance->Custom Background` page in Wordpress' admin panel?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp-admin/custom-background.php`